# OpenLayers: Zoomable WMS overlay?

Tags: maps, gis, openlayers, wms

I have a problem with WMS overlays in OpenLayers. Basically I just want to add data from a WMS server as an overlay and not as a base layer. This appears to be a very simple problem but I am unable to find a solution. If I set *singleTile* to *true*, the overlays appears over the whole map but you cannot zoom in. If it is set to *false*, only one tile is displayed at every zoom level. If I set it as a base layer, it works just fine but I really want the overlay solution so I can make it transparent and see the map behind it.

Demonstration of the problem, with a different dataset but the issue is the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/adbnC/2/

I think it might be related to some coordinate system issues but I am no expert so any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Here is the relevant section of the code that does not work as expected:

```
var pop_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Population Density in 2000",
    "http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/ows", {
        layers: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000',
        transparent: true
     }, {
         opacity: 0.5,
         isBaseLayer: false,
         // Setting single tile to true will kind of work but than one
         // cannot zoom in any more.
         singleTile: false
     }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite get what exactly is wrong here, but I think it has something to do with messed up reference systems. Here is a workaround:

[Modified Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinDueren/fjCKd/)

I changed the map projection to spherical mercator and now it seems to work fine for me:

```
var mapOptions = {
    div: "map",
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    units: "m"
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);

var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(osm);

var pop_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Population Density in 2000", "http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/ows", {
    layers: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000',
    transparent: true
}, {
    opacity: 0.5,
    isBaseLayer: false
});

map.addLayer(osm);
map.addLayer(pop_layer);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 2);​
```

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It appears to work perfectly in all the cases I tested it.Thanks again! I would upvote the answer but it appears that I do not have enough reputation yet.